# Redis-py Read LOWEST_LATENCY or NEAREST

Tags: python, redis, py-redis

Redis-py Version:
**4.2.0**

How can we enable redis-py to read from the LOWEST_LATENCY node? We are using AWS global datastore so we want to enable redis-py to read from the nearest node from the geo-distributed nearest node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't.

The Python library, according to [this Amazon article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/new-cluster-mode-support-in-redis-py/), integrated cluster support originally implemented in [this project](https://github.com/Grokzen/redis-py-cluster), so users did not need a 3rd party library for cluster support. However, at the time of writting there is no support for lowest latency mode. The supported modes are `PRIMARIES`, `REPLICAS`, `ALL_NODES` and `RANDOM`. Note that some of these are covered in the Java library, such as `REPLICAS`, that I think is `ANY_REPLICA` in Lettuce.

The `LOWEST_LATENCY` mode is implemented in the Java library, it does not seem to be a parameter supported or provided by AWS and from what I could see, it is not present in the Python library.

```
/**
 * Setting to read from the node with the lowest latency during topology discovery. Note that latency measurements are
 * momentary snapshots that can change in rapid succession. Requires dynamic refresh sources to obtain topologies and
 * latencies from all nodes in the cluster.
 * @since 6.1.7
 */
public static final ReadFrom LOWEST_LATENCY = new ReadFromImpl.ReadFromLowestCommandLatency();
```

This apparently was called NEAREST, which might mean it was somehow initially linked to geospacial proximity (but this is just a guess):

```
/**
 * Setting to read from the node with the lowest latency during topology discovery. Note that latency measurements are
 * momentary snapshots that can change in rapid succession. Requires dynamic refresh sources to obtain topologies and
 * latencies from all nodes in the cluster.
 * @deprecated since 6.1.7 as we're renaming this setting to {@link #LOWEST_LATENCY} for more clarity what this setting
 *             actually represents.
 */
@Deprecated
public static final ReadFrom NEAREST = LOWEST_LATENCY;
```

Looking at `ReadFromLowestCommandLatency()`, here's the definition. Comment has important information about the latency mesurements:

```
/**
 * Read from the node with the lowest latency during topology discovery. Note that latency measurements are momentary
 * snapshots that can change in rapid succession. Requires dynamic refresh sources to obtain topologies and latencies from
 * all nodes in the cluster.
 */
static final class ReadFromLowestCommandLatency
```

All these Readxxx methods somehow use `getNodes()`, which returns nodes sorted by latency. But this sorting occurs in the library. The library seems to implement the latency sorting, which is not done in the Python implementation.

```
// Returns the list of nodes that are applicable for the read operation. The list is ordered by latency.
List<RedisNodeDescription> getNodes();
```

I did not perform a full code analysis, but for example this method in `TopologyComparators.java` seems to confirm this:

```
/**
 * Sort partitions by latency.
 * @param clusterNodes
 * @return List containing {@link RedisClusterNode}s ordered by latency
 */
public static List<RedisClusterNode> sortByLatency(Iterable<RedisClusterNode> clusterNodes) {
    List<RedisClusterNode> ordered = LettuceLists.newList(clusterNodes);
    ordered.sort(LatencyComparator.INSTANCE);
    return ordered;
}
```

Sorry if you already know some of this, but as I took a look I thought I would post it as an answer.