# Pymongo how to set read_preference

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

How do we enable PyMongo to read from the nearest? This field db.read_preference is read-only now.

```
from pymongo import ReplicaSetConnection
from pymongo import ReadPreference

db = ReplicaSetConnection('localhost:27017', replicaSet='rs1')['my_db']
db.read_preference = ReadPreference.NEAREST
db.tag_sets = [{'secondaries': 1}]
```

Comment: So you gave up on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71641226/redis-py-read-lowest-latency-or-nearest and are using mongo now or are those two different problems to be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add it to the connection string, like so:

```
db = ReplicaSetConnection('localhost:27017?readPreference=nearest', replicaSet='rs1')['my_db']
```

Or

```
db = MongoClient("myhost:27017", read_preference=ReadPreference.NEAREST, replicaSet='rs1')['my_db']
```

For whatever reason the given syntax you're using fails, it seems it's the syntax supported for older Pymongo versions.

Answer (score 2):

PyMongo [ReadPreference](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/read_preferences.html) can also be applied at database, collection or a query level (in addition to within Connection String URI and with the [MongoClient](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html)).

```
from pymongo import ReadPreference

# Specifying read preference at database level
db1 = client.testdb1
db2 = client.get_database('testdb2', read_preference=ReadPreference.NEAREST)

# Specifying read preference at collection level
coll2 = db1.coll1.with_options(read_preference=ReadPreference.NEAREST)

# Specifying read preference for a specific query
result = db1.coll1.with_options(read_preference=ReadPreference.NEAREST).find()
```

Note the read preference set at the lower level (e.g., collection) will override the one set at the previous level (e.g., database or mongo client).

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1(per connection):**

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient, ReadPreference
>>> db = MongoClient("myhost:27017", read_preference=ReadPreference.NEAREST).test
>>> db.collection.find_one({test:1})
```

**Option 2(per query):**

```
>>> db.collection.find_one({test:1},read_preference=ReadPreference.NEAREST)
```